# Prestashop 1.5 API keep asking for Authentication

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have prestashop 1.5 installed on my server, and currently have 1 API Token for testing.

Whenever i try to access it via http://myshopdomain.com/api/ it keep asking for a username + password with a message "Authentication Required" (see attachment)

But when i try to access it directly via: http://myshopdomain.com/api/?ws_key=XXXXX it displays all available endpoints.

I already set the "Active mode CGI for PHP" to **TRUE**
I have a feeling that this has got to do with my .htaccess, but i am not sure what to do with it. Can anyone please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's right.

You must enter the key where it says user name and left you should see the endpoints.